# How to display tableView only after data fetched from web? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uitableview, uicollectionview

I encountered difficulties when loading the Collection views nested in table view cells. The content inside cells would only show after scrolling the table a couple of times. My approach was to use `DispatchGroup()` in order to fetch the data in a background thread but it didn't work. What is there to do in order to show all the information at once without scrolling through table?

**ViewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    _tableView.isHidden = true
    _tableView.dataSource = nil
    _tableView.delegate = nil
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatBlack()

    getData()

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self._tableView.isHidden = false
        self._tableView.dataSource = self
        self._tableView.delegate = self
        self._tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

**UICollectionView and UITableView datasource / OtherMethods**

```
func getData(){

        dispatchGroup.enter()

        backend.movieDelegate = self

        backend.actorDelegate = self

        backend.getMoviePopularList()

        backend.getMovieTopRatedList()

        backend.getMovieUpcomingList()

        backend.getPopularActors()

        backend.getMovieNowPlayingList()

        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }


    func transferMovies(data: [String:[MovieModel]]) {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        popularMovies = data
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    func transferActors(data: [ActorModel]) {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        popularActors = data
        dispatchGroup.leave()

    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DiscoverCell") as? DiscoverViewCell else { return UITableViewCell()}

        cell.categoryLabel.text = cell.categories[indexPath.item]
        //categories[indexPath.item]
        cell._collectionView.delegate = self
        cell._collectionView.dataSource = self
        cell._collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell._collectionView.reloadData()

        self.setUpCell(cell)

        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MovieCell", for: indexPath) as? MovieCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell()}

        if collectionView.tag == 0{

            if let movieDetails = popularMovies["Popular"]?[indexPath.item] {
                cell.updateMovieCollectionCell(movie: movieDetails)
            }
        } else if collectionView.tag == 1{

            if let movieDetails = popularMovies["Top rated"]?[indexPath.item] {

                cell.updateMovieCollectionCell(movie: movieDetails)
            }
        } else if collectionView.tag == 2{

            if let movieDetails = popularMovies["Upcoming"]?[indexPath.item] {

                cell.updateMovieCollectionCell(movie: movieDetails)

            } else if collectionView.tag == 3{

                cell.movieTitleLabel.text = popularActors?[indexPath.item].name ?? ""
                cell.moviePicture.image = popularActors?[indexPath.item].poster

            }
        } else if collectionView.tag == 4{

            if let movieDetails = popularMovies["Now playing"]?[indexPath.item] {
                cell.updateMovieCollectionCell(movie: movieDetails)
            }

        }

        return cell
    }
```

**MovieCollectionViewCell**

```
class MovieCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var moviePicture: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var movieTitleLabel: UILabel!

        func updateMovieCollectionCell(movie: MovieModel){
            moviePicture.image = movie.poster
            movieTitleLabel.text = movie.name
        }

    }
```

**DiscoverViewCell**

```
class DiscoverViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var _collectionView: UICollectionView!

        let categories = ["Popular", "Top Rated", "Upcoming", "Popular People", "Now playing"]

        @IBAction func seeMoreAction(_ sender: Any) {

        }
    }
```

My intention is to show a loading animation until all the data is fetched and the display the table view cells containing the collection views with fetched data from web.

The desired result should look like this when opening the app

[image: The desired result should look like this when opening the app]

Comment: Are the backend.get*() methods themselves synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: They're asynchronous, how can I make them function in the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you're using dispatchGroup incorrectly.

To summarize `notify()`:

- it runs the associated block when all currently queued blocks in the group are complete
- the block is only run once and then released
- if the group's queue is empty, the block is run immediately

The issue I see is that with the way your fetch code is written, the group thinks its queue is empty when you call notify. So the `notify()` block is run immediately and then you only see the cells populate when they are reloaded during scrolling.

There are two ways to populate a dispatchGroup's queue:

- call `DispatchQueue.async()` and pass the group to directly enqueue a block and associate it with the group
- manually call `enter()` when a block begins and `leave()` when it ends, which increases/decreases an internal counter on the group

The first way is safer, since you don't have to keep track of the blocks yourself, but the second one is more flexible if you don't have control over what queue a block is run on for example.

Since you're using `enter/leave`, you need to make sure that you call `enter()` for each separate work item (in your case, the asynchronous calls to `backend`), and only call `leave()` when each one those work items completes. I'm not sure how you're using the delegate methods, but there doesn't seem to one for each `backend` call, since there are 5 different calls and only 2 delegate methods. It also doesn't look like the delegate methods would be called if an error happened in the backend call.

I would recommend changing the `backend` calls to use completion blocks instead, but if you want to stick with the delegate pattern, here's how you might do it:

```
func getData(){
    backend.movieDelegate = self
    backend.actorDelegate = self

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    backend.getMoviePopularList()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    backend.getMovieTopRatedList()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    backend.getMovieUpcomingList()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    backend.getPopularActors()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    backend.getMovieNowPlayingList()

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self._tableView.isHidden = false
        self._tableView.dataSource = self
        self._tableView.delegate = self
        self._tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func transferPopularMovies(data: [MovieModel]) {
    popularMovies = data
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}

func transferTopRatedMovies(data: [MovieModel]) {
    topRatedMovies = data
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}

func transferUpcomingMovies(data: [MovieModel]) {
    upcomingMovies = data
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}

func transferActors(data: [ActorModel]) {
    popularActors = data
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}

func transferNowPlayingMovies(data: [MovieModel]) {
    nowPlayingMovies = data
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}
```

Don't forget to call the delegate methods even if there is an error to make sure the `enter/leave` calls are balanced. If you call `enter` more often than `leave`, the `notify` block never runs. If you call `leave` more often, you crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...After getting your data from backend and assigning to moviedetails, set your delegate and datasource to self and reload table.

Comment: It works only for the movie titles. The images are not displayed all at once.

Comment: Even images are being downloaded asynchronously, it takes time to load...

Answer (score 0):

Set this line into the bottom of getData() function and run

```
    self._tableView.isHidden = false
    self._tableView.dataSource = self
    self._tableView.delegate = self
    self._tableView.reloadData()
```

and remove from viewdidload()